# How to build a tool with specific libraries without breaking Fedora?

Tags: linux, compiling, software-installation

So far never needed to deviate from the standard Fedora 16 core development components. I am needing to build [clutter-mx project](https://github.com/clutter-project/mx), but this library requires glib-2.0.32. Along with this, glib-2 needs libffi-3.0.11.

I can download the source and build these libraries, however, I am concerned that installing them will break the rest of the system.

The [clutter-mx project](https://github.com/clutter-project/mx) uses autotools and looks for the glib-2 version.

The questions are:

1. If I build and install the new components, and something goes wrong, can you get back using yum, or something similar?
2. Is there a way of getting autotools to look in another directory for the installed headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sources looking for dependencies via auto-tools have a configure.ac file (and/or Makefile.am, I'm not sure on this one) in which those dependencies are defined. Most of the time people/IDEs will just put their currently installed versions of the libraries as dependency but don't actually need them in a that recent version.

You can try to modify the required verions to your versions and try to build the package.

You cannot directly make the autotools look in some alternate path but IIRC the autotools use pkg-config to determine package-installation specifics (man pkg-config). You can tell pkg-config to look in other directories by the evironmental variable PKG_CONFIG_PATH. However, the pkg-config path only works if you have the more recent libraries actually installed somewhere. But then I believe you can edit the *.pc files to force clutter-mx statically link those libraries.

If you install two versions of a library and sometimes use the one and sometimes the other you may run into problems. If you actually replace files that were put there by rpm your about screwed.

My advice is to modify the builddependencies or if need be determine why the more recent version of library XY is required and modify clutter-mx sources to not require that recent version and work with your current version. My second best advice is to get/build packages for your distribution of the requried libraries and install those. You really really shouldn't break out of the world set up by your distro, i.e. package manager. There are evil forces out there. :-)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice. We need to build the latest glib-2 as there are dependancies, but the PKG_CONFIG_PATH works well.

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to install newer Gtk/Gnome libraries in a system directory. They have poor backward compatibility, and you risk breaking existing programs.

Compile and install new libraries in a separate directory hierarchy. Run `./configure --help` to see how to specify paths to libraries and include files when you compile a library. For example, if you see

> ```
> PANGO_CFLAGS
>             C compiler flags for PANGO, overriding pkg-config
> PANGO_LIBS  linker flags for PANGO, overriding pkg-config
> ```

then set the following environment variables:

```
export PANGO_CFLAGS='-I /path/to/my/gnome/stuff/include'
export PANGO_LIBS='-L /path/to/my/gnome/stuff/libs'
```

Pass `--prefix=/path/to/my/gnome/stuff` to `./configure`, to get everything installed to your own directory.

Or, and this will be easier if you need to install a lot of libraries, rebuild everything including with [pkg-config](http://pkg-config.freedesktop.org). Install `pkg-config` under `/path/to/my/gnome/stuff` as well, then set

```
export PKG_CONFIG=/path/to/my/gnome/stuff/bin/pkg-config
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice. The PKG_CONFIG_PATH works well.